# Similar articles and exclude result with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with Eloquent and I'm displaying hotel rooms.
On each room page I want to display the other rooms on bottom, but to exclude the chosen one.

For an example we have 4 type of rooms (single, double, triple, studio).
When a user enters the double room page, on the bottom I want to be displayed the other three rooms (single, triple, studio), so in this case "single" has to be excluded.

I've created include blade file rooms-other, but how can I get the data from the database and display the other rooms?

Here are the parts of my code.

Controller:

```
public function room($slug) {
  $room = Room::whereTranslation('slug', $slug)->first();

  if($room->translate()->where('slug', $slug)->first()->locale != app()->getLocale()) {
    return redirect(route('room', $room->translate()->slug));
  }
  return view('room', compact('room'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/room/{slug}', 'RoomsController@room')->name('room');
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.front')

@section('content')
  <div class="main room">
    <div class="header-image"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top text-center">
        <div class="title"><h2>{{ $room->title }}</h2></div>
        <div class="subtitle"><h4>{{ $room->subtitle }}</h4></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="{{ Storage::url($room->image) }}" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="body">{!! $room->body !!}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      @include('includes.rooms-other')
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

As you can see from the code I've created the "rooms-other" view as include file, but how do I display the data from the other rooms?

EDIT: I know I can create another method in the controller and call in the route with the same view, but how do I get the excluded result? 
I need that with a code.

Comment: you can add new function to model to get other rooms. and in blade just call that function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So In my controller I have to create a new method. But, how do I create with excluded result? Can you show me that with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in your controller :

```
public function room($slug) {
    $room = Room::whereTranslation('slug', $slug)->first();
    $other_rooms = Room::where('id', '!=' , $room->id)->get();

    if($room->translate()->where('slug', $slug)->first()->locale != app()->getLocale()) {
          return redirect(route('room', $room->translate()->slug));
    }
    return view('room', compact('room', 'other_rooms'));
}
```

Comment: What do I put in that "something"?

Comment: Thank you very much! The  '!=' was the missing part. :)